# Flutter Change and refresh body content with Provider

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

In the Scaffold's body, I have an [IndexedStack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IndexedStack-class.html) which contains several pages. My goal is to do like a single page app.

I also have a `Drawer` for this widget (but in a separate widget). It enables to change the content via updating the index of the `IndexedStack`. This is possible because I made a `ChangeNotifier` (from `Provider`) to notify my body that the index has changed (`Consumer`).

My solution works but the problem is that `IndexedStack` loads all the pages at the beginning and won't refresh them later. I've found a trick for that, but I need to call `setState()` -> I can't do it from my `Drawer`. So, is there a way to trigger `setState()` when the index from the `ChangeNotifier` changes ? Atm I can read its value, but how to know when it is changing ?

**Update:**

In scaffold's body (with `Consumer`):

```
IndexedStack(
  index: navigation.pageIndex,  // -> from Consumer 
  children: [
     Page0(),
     Page1(uid: navigation.uid), // -> from Consumer
  ]
)
```

navigation_provider.dart:

```
class NavigationProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  int _pageIndex = 0;
  String _uid = '';

  int get pageIndex => _pageIndex;

  set pageIndex(int i) {
    _pageIndex = i;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  String get uid => _uid;

  set uid(String uid) {
    _uid = uid;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

In my drawer, I do (when I want Page1 to be displayed):

```
Provider.of<NavigationProvider>(context,listen: false).uid = 'newValue';
Provider.of<NavigationProvider>(context, listen: false).pageIndex = 1;
```

**Result: Page1() is always called with uid = '' (no update)**

Comment: you may use consumer widget for inner item

Comment: What do you mean ? I've already have a Consumer to retrieve the index's value for my IndexedStack. But I also need to trigger setState() everytime the index's value changes.

Comment: can you include sample code-snippet that will reproduce the same error

Comment: I don't have error. ```IndexedStack``` is not supposed to rebuild every page, but you can do it if you change his children and do ```setState()``` . But I don't know how to do ```setState()``` when I am currently in the Drawer widget.

Comment: I've edited and included some code